# Embed volume control

Tags: html, embed

Using embed to embed music might sound oldschool, but I don't have any other choice (any method used now doesn't accept my files).

```
<embed hidden="true" volume="10" src="/app/upload/1287860161768038.mp3" />
```

Music starts to play, but volume is always 100% (not 10 like here). I don't know how to repair it, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player that is going to be used will be whatever player is installed on the system to handle mp3 content so results may be a bit random.

Yahoo and several others have javascripts that make embedding mp3 a lot easier, you don't need to go through the troubles of having the right plugins installed.

http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/

http://code.google.com/p/mp3player/

Type= can be used to control which player and which controls

TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" would normally be Windows Media player

TYPE="audio/mpeg" would normally be quicktime.

Using a script removes these browser vs browser headaches.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, but I finally adjusted jPlayer and it works

Answer (score 0):

It appears from something that I just read, that if you want to set the Audio Volume to 10%, then the correct 'amount' would be 0.10

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp