# Control volume level of mp3 playing in a hidden embed tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden  tag in a page which plays a mp3 music file. I am trying to make a control using javascript to increase or decrease the volume level.

Note:- I do not have luxury to use HTML5.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
music = 'music/01_Candle_in_the_Wind.mp3';
$('body').append('<embed src="'+ music +'" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
```

Comment: @joseph I have added my code in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed volume control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005686/embed-volume-control)

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't concatenate attribute values in like that.  The data isn't escaped properly, and this could lead to misinterpreted HTML.  I recommend creating the element (static properties that you escape yourself are okay), and then setting the `src` attribute with jQuery's `.attr()` function.